# MySQL select from group with fallback

Tags: mysql

Have some trouble with query. I am attempting create select from table where deposit_type_language_id=3 or if row does not exist 1 (as fallback) with grouping by deposit_type_id.

```
 +-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
    | deposit_type_id | deposit_type_language_id | deposit_type_name |
    +-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
    |               1 |                        1 | jewellery         |
    |               1 |                        2 | bijuterii         |
    |               1 |                        3 | šperky            |
    |               2 |                        1 | equipment         |
    |               2 |                        2 | tehnica           |
    +-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

I am attempting with below query:

```
SELECT t1.* from deposit_type AS t1 
       INNER JOIN 
           ( SELECT deposit_type_id, min(deposit_type_language_id) from
                    deposit_type group by deposit_type_id ) AS t2 
       ON t1.deposit_type_id=t2.deposit_type_id group by deposit_type_id;
```

The output is:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| deposit_type_id | deposit_type_language_id | deposit_type_name |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|               1 |                        1 | jewellery         |
|               2 |                        1 | equipment         |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

But I am attempting achieve something like below:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| deposit_type_id | deposit_type_language_id | deposit_type_name |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|               1 |                        3 | šperky            |
|               2 |                        1 | equipment         |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Where is my mistake?

Table structure:

```
deposit_type | CREATE TABLE `deposit_type` (
  `deposit_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deposit_type_language_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deposit_type_name` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deposit_type_id`,`deposit_type_language_id`),
  KEY `deposit_type_language_id` (`deposit_type_language_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `deposit_type_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`deposit_type_language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.deposit_type_id
     , COALESCE(y.deposit_type_language_id,x.deposit_type_language_id) deposit_type_language_id
     , COALESCE(y.deposit_type_name,x.deposit_type_name) deposit_type_name 
  FROM deposit_type x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN deposit_type y 
    ON y.deposit_type_id = x.deposit_type_id 
   AND y.deposit_type_language_id = 3 
 WHERE x.deposit_type_language_id = 1;
```

Comment: @Strawberrry, hey man your answer seems to be correct. I am learning your answer, thanks!

Comment: if you would like in two words explain your thought, please.

Comment: @vit The left [outer] join returns a value if a valid one exists, or NULL otherwise. COALESCE then simply disregards the NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

@CFreitas you answer incorrect a little bit but gave me one thought. We should add one more comparison, see below.

```
SELECT t1.* from deposit_type AS t1 
         INNER JOIN 
               (SELECT deposit_type_id, max(deposit_type_language_id) as dtl FROM deposit_type 
                   WHERE deposit_type_language_id=3 or deposit_type_language_id=1 group by deposit_type_id ) AS t2 
               ON t1.deposit_type_id=t2.deposit_type_id and t1.deposit_type_language_id=t2.dtl group by deposit_type_id;
```

The output is:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| deposit_type_id | deposit_type_language_id | deposit_type_name |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|               1 |                        3 | šperky            |
|               2 |                        1 | equipment         |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```